# How to test iOS framework connecting with MFI device

Tags: ios, debugging, sdk, frameworks, mfi

Currently I have two project, one project is SDK project, which can generate the framework (will communicate with hardware firmware). Another project is a testSDK project, which import the SDK framework. It has the easy UI to test all the functions in SDK.

Because our testSDK app must be connected with hardware(MFI) through lighting port to work, I have no idea how to use Xcode console to debug in this scenario.
I can only use log now. Any better suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I still don't have any answers yet. The only thing now I can do it is through logging. I cannot do the real-time debug in such scenario.